# ArgumentError: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 when creating CSV from TempFile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, encoding, utf-8

I have the following two lines of a code that take an uploaded CSV file from `params` and return a hash of `Contact` objects. The code works fine when I input a CSV with UTF-8 encoding. If I try to upload a CSV with another type of encoding though, it breaks. How can I adjust the code to detect the encoding of the uploaded file and convert to UTF-8?

```
CSV::Converters[:blank_to_nil] = lambda { |field| field && field.empty? ? nil : field }
csv = CSV.new(params[:file].tempfile.open, headers: true, header_converters: :symbol, converters: [:all, :blank_to_nil]).to_a.map {|row| row.to_hash }
```

**This question is not a duplicate!** I've seen numerous other questions on here revolving around the same encoding issue, but the specifics of those are different than my case. Specifically, I need a way convert the encoding of a `TempFile` generated from my `params` hash. Other solutions I've seen involve encoding `String` and `File` objects, as well as passing an encoding option to `CSV.parse` or `CSV.open`. I've tried those solutions already without success.

I've tried passing in an encoding option to `CSV.new`, like so:

```
csv = CSV.new(params[:file].tempfile.open, encoding: 'iso-8859-1:utf-8', headers: true, header_converters: :symbol, converters: [:all, :blank_to_nil]).to_a.map {|row| row.to_hash }
```

I've also tried this:

```
csv = CSV.new(params[:file].tempfile.open, encoding: 'iso-8859-1:utf-8', headers: true, header_converters: :symbol, converters: [:all, :blank_to_nil]).to_a.map {|row| row.to_hash }
```

I've tried adjusting my converter as well, like so:

```
CSV::Converters[:blank_to_nil] = lambda { |field| field && field.empty? ? nil : field.encode('utf-8') }
```

I'm looking for a programatic solution here that does not require the user to convert their CSV to the proper encoding.

Comment: There are gems for detecting character encoding that are pretty easy to google.

Answer (score 1):

I've also had to deal with this problem and here is how I finally solved it.

```
  CSV.open(new_csv_file, 'w') do |csv_object|
    lines = File.open(uploaded_file).read
    lines.each_line do |line|
      csv_object << line.encode!("utf-8", "utf-8", invalid: :replace, undef: :replace, replace: '').parse_csv
    end
  end
  CSV.new(File.read(new_csv_file))
```

Basically go through every line, sanitize it and shove it into a new CSV file.
Hope that leads you and other in the right direction.

Comment: I'm having trouble adapting your code to mine. Where is `new_csv_file` on line 1 defined?

Comment: new_csv_file would be a Tempfile. You can define it like so:
`new_csv_file = Tempfile.new("some_csv_file")`

Comment: Did you get this working or are you still having issues? If it did fix your problem please upvote.

Comment: It works for one of my sample CSV files that I created in my code editor but not the other one that I exported from Excel. I still haven't gotten my CSV import method working right but it's been low on my agenda. Hoping to come back to it in more depth next week.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the vote. You might want to try exporting as csv (Windows comma separated) from Excel. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [filemagic](https://github.com/blackwinter/ruby-filemagic) to detect the encoding of a file, although it's not 100% accurate. It bases on system's `file` command tool, so I'm not sure if it works on windows.